# How to show tamil, kanada in textview when fetching data from JSON?

Tags: android, utf-8

I am fetching some data from Url in JSON format.

Some strings are in south Indian languages like Tamil,Telugu.

But when I display these data in text view it shows like à²à³à²£à²¿à²¤à²¾à²à³à²·à²
How can I fix this issue?
My code to fetch json array is below

```
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                if (jsonobject.getString("resType").contains("Books")) {
                    {
                        Details detailAll = new Details();


                        detailAll.setName(jsonobject.optString("Tamil"));
                        detailAll.setUrl(jsonobject.optString("resLink"));
                        details.add(detailAll);}
                    }
```

Comment: Try  [Multi Language Support](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/)

Comment: The data is not  hard coded @kirankumar.

Comment: you have to add the tamil,kannada fonts in your assets. Set the fonts to your textview.

Answer (score 1):

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
        if (is != null) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    //"UTF-8"  "iso-8859-1"
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);

        }
```

I have to use UTF-8 instead of iso-8859-1 and it solved the problem.